# Как правильно: в зеркало или через зеркало?

Tags: выбор-слов

Оставайтесь в машине, — велел он, посмотрев на нас в (через) зеркало заднего вида.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Правильно: *Оставайтесь в машине, — велел он, посмотрев на нас **через зеркало** заднего вида.*

**В зеркале** можно увидеть только отражение, хотя мы говорим: посмотри на себя в зеркало. Но в этом случае своё отражение мы отождествляем с собой.

**Примеры:**

Водитель вздрогнул, **взглянул на Стаса через зеркало** заднего обзора и успокоился. [Н. Леонов, А. Макеев. Эхо дефолта (2000-2004)]

**Через зеркало он видел** всю комнату: Вареника, сидящего на диване, женщин, сжавшихся в углу, ну и себя, разумеется, крупным планом. [Сергей Таранов. Мстители (1999)]

Та не знала, что Настя **через зеркало видит** ее лицо. [Л. М. Леонов. Барсуки (1924)]

Answer (score 3):

Можно **видеть** кого-то *в зеркал**е*** (совершенно не обязательно себя - зеркало может находиться под любым углом) или *"глядя в зеркал**о**"*, однако проблематично (как минимум, стилистически) **смотреть** одновременно **в зеркало** и **на кого-то**. Что-нибудь одно: если вы *смотрите на кого-то* (прямо или *через зеркало*), то *сосредоточиваетесь* на нём, а если смотрите *в зеркало*, то видите всю "предлагаемую" им картину; далее у вас есть выбор - смотреть ли через это самое зеркало на что-либо конкретное. Поэтому предлагаемое решение: "*смотреть **на** кого-либо **через зеркало**"*.

Answer (score 2):

Думаю, допустимы оба варианта. Поэтому в этом выборе можете просто довериться собственному "чутью языка".

Цитаты в пользу варианта "через" уже привели в другом ответе, поэтому я приведу несколько цитат с вариантом "в". (Таких цитат много, в том числе и с "зеркалом заднего вида", но я стараюсь выбирать только известных авторов или солидные издания.)

> Незнакомая девушка стояла, вероятно, за ним, на пороге этой двери,
>   пока он смотрел на нее в зеркало. (Зинаида Гиппиус)
>
> Так и смотрел на нее в зеркало. (Борис Акунин)
>
> Шофер внимательно посмотрел на них в зеркало. (Эдуард Тополь)
>
> ...Михаил Яблочков, или попросту Миша, Мишенька, как позволил называть
>   себя, — посмотрел на него в зеркало... (журнал "Театральная жизнь")
>
> Грегори в первый раз посмотрел на него в зеркало. (журнал "Иностранная
>   литература")
>
> Алькальд предложил ему сесть и, продолжая бриться, посмотрел на него в
>   зеркало. (журнал "Новый мир")

**Дополнение.**

Мы с Розенталем оказались в меньшинстве, но я всё же процитирую его "Справочник управления...".

> **В — ЧЕРЕЗ.** При обозначении предмета, через который   совершается действие, предлоги синонимичны, но различаются  оттенками значения:
>   *подглядывать в щелку/через щелку*;   *смотреть в замочную скважину/через
>   замочную скважину* (во втором  варианте каждой пары внимание
>   акцентируется на предмете,  благодаря которому совершается действие; в
>   первом варианте на  передний план выступает указание на действие,
>   совершаемое  с целью «чтобы увидеть»).

Я не думаю, что можно просто взять и объявить вне закона выражения "посмотрел на что-то в зеркало / в окно / в бинокль / в подзорную трубу / в иллюминатор" и т.п. Эти выражения знакомы каждому с детства, они встречаются в тысячах книг самых известных авторов.

Comment: Так у Вас только пример с шофёром про машинное зеркало.

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой Так ведь я сказал, что есть много примеров и с зеркалом заднего вида/обзора. Просто авторы/издания там не настолько маститые (или нужно долго искать). А примеры я привёл с "смотреть **в зеркало**", поскольку в другом ответе сказано, что так говорить нельзя, и это был единственный аргумент в пользу выбора предлога "через".

Comment: @ grizzly Я могу смотреть или на него, или в зеркало, смотреть в двух направлениях у меня не получается.

Comment: @Sharon А у меня получается смотреть "на него в зеркало" в одном направлении. Впрочем, для меня очевидно, что это вопрос вкусов (языкового чутья), и я не вижу аргументов ни с одной ни с другой стороны. Цитаты в пользу своей точки зрения я привёл, они всяко не хуже Ваших :)

Comment: (Поздновато зашла на сайт.) Я — с Вами и Розенталем. (Правда, в некоторых случаях есть нюансы — как же без них?)

Answer (score 1):

Это дополнение к уже данному ответу в части добавления **отсутствующих аргументов.**

Итак, я могу повторить. ***Посмотреть на нас через  зеркало*** – это правильно,  ***посмотреть на нас в зеркало*** – эта форма имеет грамматическую погрешность.  Это мое мнение, которое я хочу объяснить, но при этом я с уважением отношусь к мнению людей, которые считают эти варианты равноправными.

Следует различать глаголы ***смотреть*** и ***видеть***.

Глагол ***смотреть*** в своем основном значении **непереходный**: смотреть – это **направлять взгляд**, чтобы увидеть кого – что-н.  (его переходное значение в сочетании «смотреть фильм»  является вторичным).

***Видеть*** – этот, напротив,  глагол переходный со значением «воспринимать зрением».

**Видеть в зеркале можно что угодно и кого угодно**: себя, других людей и всё окружающее пространство, при этом неважно, что мы видим всего лишь отраженную действительность (ведь всё это мы просто воспринимаем в виде информации).

**Но вот смотрим мы только в определенную сторону, а не в два места сразу: или в зеркало, или на сидящих сзади людей.** Если  они отражаются в зеркале,  то оптическое устройство предлагает нам их **мнимое изображение**, на которое мы тоже смотрим.

Таким образом,  посмотреть на людей за нашей спиной можно **или повернувшись к ним, или через зеркало (= с помощью зеркала),** когда мы видим их отражение в нём.

Да какая тут разница, скажете вы, и так всё ясно. **Да, конечно, семантика вполне ясная, но не грамматика.**

Грамматика задает глаголу «смотреть» вполне определенное значение – **направить взгляд куда, на что, во что**; законы оптики она не учитывает. Но при этом она фиксирует  **наличие двух противоположных направлений для нашего взгляда**  и определяет такое сочетание **как ошибку**.

**Грамматика – это наука формальная, консервативная и не терпит никаких неточностей**, которые воспринимаются на слух как нечто дискомфортное. И это правильно, так как грамматика является структурным каркасом языка.  Без формальной основы  (на одной лексике) он, вероятно, очень скоро перестал бы вообще существовать, смешался бы с другими наречиями.

Поэтому требования к грамматической правильности речи должны быть особенно строгими, **и свободу выбора, когда разрешаются оба варианта, желательно обосновать**.

**А вот смотреть в окно, щёлку, в замочную скважину мы, разумеется, можем.** Также можем смотреть в комнату **через замочную скважину,** здесь ограничений нет, так как взгляд направлен **в одну определенную сторону**.

Answer (score -1):

**Оставайтесь в машине, — велел он, посмотрев на нас в (через) зеркало заднего вида.** 
По-моему, это самое "посмотрев" - вносит сомнения, а почему не "глядя" либо "смотря"? 
"Велел он, глядя на нас в зеркало..." - выражение призвано указать на то, что человек смотрит в зеркало (направление взгляда). 
"Велел он, глядя на нас через зеркало..." - выражение призвано указать на то, что человек смотрит именно на нас, но через зеркало.